# does rdd.saveAsTextFile() saves the output file on data note?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

when i call `rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs file path")`, it's creating the multiple part files as output.

Does each and every part file will be available on different data node or all the part files are available in namenode?

If the part files are available on different data nodes, does it mean the path whatever i am passing for the saveAsTextFile() method is available in all the data nodes.. right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an HDFS question, the fact you're producing this file and writing it on HDFS using Spark is incidental.

Each part of the file will be **available** to any HDFS client, whether that client is located on one of the machines of your cluster or not. The files will be **stored** on your datanodes, with one part in each of them.